# how do i make it print the multiplication table in the created file?

Tags: python

I've been trying to put a print statement inside the loop to no avail.

```
def individualizing_file(number: int) -> None:
    increasing_number: int = number
    with open(f"file_{increasing_number}.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(f"Multiplication table for + {n}")
        for _ in range(10):
                #print(n*2) 

                increasing_number += n
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input("Enter a number between 1-9: "))
    individualizing_file(n)
```

Tried to put a print statement in the for loop but it prints nothing inside the file_n file.

Comment: use `f.write` instead of `print`

Comment: Or use `print(n*2, file=f)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `print(file=f)`:

```
def individualizing_file(number: int) -> None:
    with open(f"file_{number}.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(f"Multiplication table for + {n}")
        for multiple in range(10):
            print(number * multiple, file=f)
```

Unlike using `f.write`, `print` automatically adds a newline at the end. It also accepts any type and not just strings.

For reference to more print options see: [the documentation for print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print). For example if you want to change the ending character or separator.

Comment: Thank you, but its only showing n*2 over and over again?

Comment: Maybe you meant to write `n*_` instead of 2?

Comment: Where is *n* defined?

Comment: Added full code now

Comment: You don't want to use `n` inside the function. Avoid using global variables inside functions, use the function parameters instead.